# Inter-service Communication Architecture Using WCF, Dependency Injection, and Unit Testing

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, architecture, soa

I'm new to WCF and in a large part, also distributed programming.  I am working on a project that requires 4 discrete services.

I am trying to correctly define the responsibilities for each component of each service.  Suppose I have service B which needs to communicate with service A.  For each service, I have defined the service implementation class, the service host, and a proxy class.

In order to unit test, I am using dependency injection - since service B needs to communicate with service A, I have passed an instance of A's proxy class as a constructor argument to service B.

When I am unit testing service B, I must have A's service host up and running.

1. Is this the wrong way of going about dependency injection?  If so, why, and how do you recommend I do it?
2. Is there a better way of going about dependency injection?
3. Should I have to run the service host to get the right results in the unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using

- [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) instead of generated clients.

  ```
  ChannelFactory<IHello> clientFactory = new ChannelFactory<IHello>("targetConfiguration");
  IHello client = clientFactory.CreateChannel();
  string result = client.SayHello();
  ```
- Interface types wherever possible
- one of the mock object frameworks ([example](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)) to inject interface implementations when writing your tests.

Regarding your third question, the answer is "No" if your aim is testing particular small units (the whole point of unit testing :). But it's always better to write some integration tests to make sure you don't have any serialization/hosting problems.